# Where in the Aruch HaShulchan He'Atid are Hilchot Sotah?

Tags: halacha, aruch-hashulchan

I have an Aruch HaShulchan He'Atid, as well as a normal Aruch HaShulchan, and I'm looking up something about Sotah for a Chaburah. Does anyone know where I can find Hilchot Sotah in the Aruch HaShulchan?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48727/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hilchot Sotah is in the regular Aruch Hashulchan. It is one siman long and it is the very last siman in the Even Ha'ezer section (# 178). The siman is titled:

> דיני סוטה בזמן הבית ובזמן הזה ובו פ"ז סעיפים
>
> The laws of Sotah in the times of the temple and nowadays, and it contains 87 paragraphs.

[Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=766) is the first page.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good thing you Mi Yodeya Chevrah are so on top of your game, because I need it for tomorrow.